# How to avoid to common lines in the output file using diffLib in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am newbie of python coding and struck with a problem. 
When i am comparing two .sql files, the common lines are being displayed in the output file and requirement is to capture only tables that are modified.
The common lines in both files is not expected to be displayed in the file (diff_of_files.sql). The logic should be generic not pertained to this below program. If have huge database the common table names should never be displayed.

### Python script

```
import difflib

def main():
  rawfromlines = open('command_file.sql', 'r').readlines()
  tolines = open('new_command_file.sql', 'r').readlines()

  list_f1 = []
  list_f2 = []

  for f1 in rawfromlines:
     for part in f1.replace('\n','').split(','):
       list_f1.append(part)

  for f2 in tolines:
     for part in f2.replace('\n','').split(','):
       list_f2.append(part)


  targetfile = open('diff_of_files.sql', 'w')

  differ = difflib.Differ()
  diffs = list(differ.compare(list_f1, list_f2))

  for diff in diffs:
   print diff

  i= 0;
  length = len(diffs)
  while(i<length):
   if(diffs[i].startswith('  ')):
      lines.append('  ' +diffs[i][2:])
   elif(diffs[i].startswith('- ')):
      if(diffs[i+1].startswith('? ')) and (diffs[i+2].startswith('+ ')):
        lines.append('! ' + diffs[i+2][2:] + "-->  " + diffs[i][2:])
        i= i+2
      elif(diffs[i+1].startswith('+ ')) and (diffs[i+2].startswith('? ')):
        lines.append('! ' + diffs[i+1][2:]+ "-->  " + diffs[i][2:])
        i= i+2
      else:
        lines.append('- ' + diffs[i][2:])
   elif (diffs[i].startswith('+ ')):
      lines.append('+  ' +diffs[i][2:])

   i = i+1

  for line in lines:
     if line.startswith('  CREATE'):
        stripped_line = line.strip()
     else:
        stripped_line = line.rstrip()
     if stripped_line:
        targetfile.write(stripped_line+'\n')
  #print lines

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### file1.sql

```
CREATE TABLE SALARY
(
 SALARY int
 ID int
);
CREATE TABLE JOB1
(
 EMP1 int
);
CREATE TABLE EMP
(
 EMP VARCHAR2
 ID  INT
);
```

### file2.sql

```
CREATE TABLE SALARY
(
 SALARY short int
 EMPNAME VARCHAR2(255)
 ID int
);
CREATE TABLE JOB1
(
 EMP1 int
);
CREATE TABLE EMP
(
 EMP VARCHAR2
 ID  INT
);
CREATE TABLE BRIDGE
(
 ID int
);
```

### diff_of_files.sql

```
CREATE TABLE SALARY
  (
!  SALARY short int-->   SALARY int
+   EMPNAME VARCHAR2(255)
   ID int
  );
CREATE TABLE JOB1
  (
   EMP1 int
  );
CREATE TABLE EMP
  (
   EMP VARCHAR2
   ID  INT
  );
+  CREATE TABLE BRIDGE
+  (
+   ID int
+  );
```

### Expected Output

```
CREATE TABLE SALARY
      (
    !  SALARY short int-->   SALARY int
    +   EMPNAME VARCHAR2(255)
       ID int
      );
    +  CREATE TABLE BRIDGE
    +  (
    +   ID int
    +  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want

> to capture only tables that are modified

you may need to first run a `differ.compare` on a list of table elements like this.

```
import difflib
import re

s1 = open("file1.sql", "r", encoding="utf-8").read()
s2 = open("file2.sql", "r", encoding="utf-8").read()
list_f1 = re.split('\);\n', s1)[:-1]
list_f2 = re.split('\);\n', s2)[:-1]
differ = difflib.Differ()
diffs = list(differ.compare(list_f1, list_f2))

list_diff = [d for d in diffs if d.startswith('+ CREATE TABLE')]
```

That returns:

```
+ CREATE TABLE SALARY
(
 SALARY short int
 EMPNAME VARCHAR2(255)
 ID int

+ CREATE TABLE BRIDGE
(
 ID int
```

and then run another `differ.compare` on the table elements of `list_f1` and `list_f2` matching `list_diff`.